# Proof request of $p(A) < 1 \space \text{iff} \space \lim_{k \to \infty} A^k = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I'm seeking a proof to the following lemma that I found being stated without being proven at my ***Numerical Linear Algebra*** course textbook, which involves a correlation between the spectral radius of a matrix $A$, $p(A)$ and the limit of the power of $A$ :

> Let $p(A)$ denote the spectral radius of the matrix $A$.
>
> Then, it is $p(A) <1$ **if and only if** $\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k = 0$.

Comment: A proof is given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius